# Feathers/sequelize - how to concat 2 query for same field in 1

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, feathersjs

Let's assume there are 2 query here in my hook function

```
context.params.query['id'] = { '$like': '%B%' }
context.params.query['id'] = [ 'ABC', 'CDF', 'SSS', 'BBD', 'DDD', 'ASF' ]
```

I want to concat these 2 query in into something like

```
context.params.query['id'] = XXXXXXX
```

so that it return all record with id 'ABC' and 'BBD'